# Git: git svn rebase failed. RA layer request failed

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, fetch, rebase

I did a `git svn rebase` and I got this:

```
r58087 = a2530aabd7ce119d35f63954e075b1c86067809d (refs/remotes/git-svn)

RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/svn/path/to/repo': REPORT of '//default': Could not read chu
nk delimiter: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.local) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 282
```

Everytime I do a `git svn rebase` again I get

```
Index mismatch: 4c97d1eea751f79ddf4e58f48f41e89dc8d254bd != 35962f4b5051693558a975b48ff903f061908235
rereading a2530aabd7ce119d35f63954e075b1c86067809d
```

I can't update my `git-svn` repository, anyone know what to do? I also did a `git reflog` and reverted to the version I was before the first `git svn rebase` and I get the same thing.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions in reverse order.

```
Index mismatch: 4c97d1eea751f79ddf4e58f48f41e89dc8d254bd != 35962f4b5051693558a975b48ff903f061908235
rereading a2530aabd7ce119d35f63954e075b1c86067809d
```

This basically means that it has not been able to successfully, or completely, read the named revision, and so it is starting to fetch from svn again from that revision. In your case it is `r58087` of your repository that is causing you problems.

Based on this [blogpost](http://randomallsorts.blogspot.nl/2011/10/using-git-svn-with-large-repository.html), it seems most likely that this revision is too large, and the server is timing out while you are trying to retrieve it.

Based on the collective wisdom of the internet, you have a couple of choices:

1. You can try to upgrade the server, assuming that you have that capability to a later/latest svn version.
2. You can upgrade your svn client to a later version, and force your git-svn to use that.

Should you want to go down the second route, then, on Mac, you can `brew install subversion --perl`, and then add something like

```sh
export PERLLIB=/usr/local/opt/subversion/Library/Perl/$(perl -e '$a=$^V; $a=~s/v//; $a=~s/\.[0-9]+$//; print $a')/darwin-thread-multi-2level/
```

to your `.bashrc`.